# Display Hover instead of Href for conditional check

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a very basic html requirement where on some parameter value, I need to hide the hyperlink on the text and show the hover on the text.

Below is my test html.How should I handle my Javascript where when accesscode =10, I should show only hover not href?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<h1>test Heading</h1>
<p>Test screen.</p>

 <a id="tagUrl" class="button" href='https://growthModeltest.com' target="_blank" rel="MonthlyReport">Learn More</a>

</body>
<script>
var accessCode= 10;
var hideElem = document.getElementById("tagUrl");
if(accessCode == 10){
        //should not display the link, instead show the hover.
        hideElem.href = '#';
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You select the element before it is rendered.....

Comment: I moved the script at the bottom but my question still is, how to display the href conditional. I need to show hove instead of href for certain param value.

Comment: no clue what you mean it should show the hover.....

Comment: @epascarello my requirement is to show the hyperlink for some user roles only. If the user doesnt have specific privileges instead of showing the hyperlink, i want to show hover saying that 'Link is not available for you'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove **target="_blank"** as well from the link and if you do not want user to redirect to top of the page. You can use **javascript:void(0)** inside href tag to avoid this

**Try this:**

```js
var accessCode = 10;
var hideElem = document.getElementById("tagUrl");
if (accessCode == 10) {
  //should not display the link, instead show the hover.
  hideElem.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
  hideElem.removeAttribute('target');
  hideElem.title = 'Link is not active now';
}
```

```html
<h1>test Heading</h1>
<p>Test screen.</p>

<a id="tagUrl" class="button" href='https://growthModeltest.com' target="_blank" rel="MonthlyReport">Learn More</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a tooltip that's displayed when you hover over the link, assign the `title` property.

```js
var accessCode = 10;
var hideElem = document.getElementById("tagUrl");
if (accessCode == 10) {
  //should not display the link, instead show the hover.
  hideElem.href = '#';
  hideElem.title = 'Link is not active now';
}
```

```html
<h1>test Heading</h1>
<p>Test screen.</p>

<a id="tagUrl" class="button" href='https://growthModeltest.com' target="_blank" rel="MonthlyReport">Learn More</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the update but I still do not want user to click on the link when accessCode ==10. hideElem.href = '#'; will still take user to next window. Basically I want to disable the link and show hover on it.

Comment: @MSV did you try that snippet? Clicking the link won't redirect the user anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with code below.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Disable Link using JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<h1>test Heading</h1>
<p>Test screen.</p>

 <a id="tagUrl" class="button" href='https://growthModeltest.com' target="_blank" rel="MonthlyReport">Learn More</a>

</body>
 
<script>
    var lnk = document.getElementById('tagUrl');
    var accessCode = 10;
 if (accessCode == 10) {
 lnk.title="'Link is not available for you";
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.id === lnk.id) {
    
                e.preventDefault();         // Comment this line to enable the link tag again.
            }
        });
    }}
</script>
</html>
```